# Javax and Jargs unresolved dependencies in Maven

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I'm working on an old program that my lab had abandoned in 2007 and I'm supposed to make sure it can be easily compiled. The old developer is long gone and there is no documentation on how to compile it. The fact that I've never used Maven before makes things even more complicated.

Here's what I've been doing so far:

In the project directory, i run:

> mvn package

and the compilation fails at the directory 'rusa' with the following error message:

> [INFO] Building rusa 1.0-SNAPSHOT
>   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   [WARNING] The POM for de.wolfgang:jargs:jar:1.0 is missing, no dependency information available
>   [WARNING] The POM for de.wolfgang:javax:jar:1.0 is missing, no dependency information available
>
> ...
>
> [INFO] rusa .............................................. FAILURE [0.041s]
>
> ...
>
> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project rusa: Could not resolve dependencies for project de.wolfgang:rusa:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: de.wolfgang:jargs:jar:1.0, de.wolfgang:javax:jar:1.0: Failure to find de.wolfgang:jargs:jar:1.0 in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

where 'wolfgang' is the username of the previous dev. The groupId 'de.wolfgang' is defined in the project's pom.xml and under the parent tag in rusa's pom.xml.

Here are the failing dependencies defined in rusa's pom.xml:

> ```
> <dependency>
>    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
>    <artifactId>jargs</artifactId>
>    <version>1.0</version>
>  </dependency>
>  <dependency>
>    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
>    <artifactId>javax</artifactId>
>    <version>1.0</version>
>  </dependency>
> ```

Am i supposed to replace the groupId with my username? Are these dependencies out-of-date? Do I need to specify where maven can find the dependencies? I'm new to Maven, and every tutorial is overly complicated. I'd really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that those two artifacts where developed by wolfgang himself. So he built them locally, that means they will be installed on the local repository on his computer. When you use another computer, you have to build it yourself (by calling `mvn install`). So unless you do not have the sources or at least the jars for these two dependent artifacts, you will probaly not be able to build the project.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I believe jargs refers to https://github.com/purcell/jargs/ and javax is just javax from oracle. If I can download and compile thoses, what can I do to make sure maven find those jars?

Comment: I am not sure if that are the required artifacts, because the groupId is different. If these are the correct ones, you should think about changing the pom of "rusa" to point at the correct dependencies. The page you linked even has an installation guide.